# Remove " character from REGEXEXTRACT result

Tags: google-sheets

Im looking for a way to remove the last character (") returned by my REGEXEXTRACT formula which is:

```
=SI(ESTNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\nmarket_hash_name: ""(.*)")),"",REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\nmarket_hash_name: ""(.*)"))
```

The result right now is > Sticker | Battle Scarred"
And i'd like to remove the " at the end.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Try `=LEFT(=SI(ESTNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\nmarket_hash_name: ""(.*)")),"",REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\nmarket_hash_name: ""(.*)"))
,LEN(=SI(ESTNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\nmarket_hash_name: ""(.*)")),"",REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\nmarket_hash_name: ""(.*)"))
)-1)`

Comment: It gives me an error :/

Comment: What is you input data in `B2` cell?

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(CAR(10),SPLIT(IMPORTDATA(CONCAT("https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods/sell_order?game=csgo&goods_id=",REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"goods_id=(\d+)")))&CAR(10),CAR(10))))`

Comment: It returns this: [link](https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods/sell_order?game=csgo&goods_id=769121)

Comment: Instead of `"\nmarket_hash_name: ""(.*)"`, try this: `"\nmarket_hash_name: ""(.*)"""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to suggest solid formulas without access to the actual spreadsheet and data, because we have no context. The task becomes even more difficult when there are language differences in the formula elements (this particular Stack site has mostly English-language volunteer contributors and visitors).

However (and this is an educated yet untested guess), you can try this:

`=SI.ERROR( REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "market_hash_name:\s*" & CARACTER(34) & "([^" & CARACTER(34) & "]*)") )`

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Would you please take a moment to mark my answer post as "Best Answer" now? This lets the other volunteers know that the issue has been resolved. And it helps future site visitors find relevant answers more quickly.